# Java get referer URI?

Tags: java, http, servlets

I want the exact same method as [getRequestURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29), but I want to use it on the referer. Is this possible?

I would like to turn `http://www.example.com/my/path?vars=true` into `/my/path`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: are you looking for something in the servlet api or code that does what you want.

Comment: Please look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648984/httpservletrequest-how-to-obtain-the-referring-url) and its answer, it'll tell you how to get the request URI as well as the pitfalls of trusting it.

Comment: @aaamos, That's not at all what I am talking about.

Comment: Ah, didn't see your edit when I posted my comment. Your phrase "use it on the referer" is still a bit misleading. Jon's answer should do it for you then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want something like this?

```
String refererURI = new URI(request.getHeader("referer")).getPath();
```

Comment: That looks like something that would work :). I'll give it a try right now.

Comment: Yup, that worked! I remember coming across this when looking things up, but it hadn't worked for whatever reason. I'll have to figure it out when I get back into work.

Comment: Are there constants in the servlet API defining common header names?