# Allow only "prerequisite" forwarding URL to access a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Say for example I have a servlet named FooServlet, mapped to /foo.

There are two other servlets named BarServlet and CarServlet, mapepd to /bar and /car, respectively.

Now, if a user does a direct access to www.example.com/foo, they should be rejected. BUT if the request comes from a forward on /bar or /car, I will allow access to /foo.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see this question: [Java get referer URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996561/java-get-referer-uri)

You can check the referer header in the request to make sure they are coming from one of your other servlets.

Comment: I deserve a downvote for asking this question, but this question clarifies the term "referer URI". Thank you for that good read.

Comment: Yep. It's named appropriately.

Comment: Hey again. By the way, do you recommend putting this on filters?

Comment: Not if you're only going to use it for this one case. It's pretty simple.

Comment: Nope. I have a "web" of decision making URLs. Means I have a lot of these. :D

Comment: Then yes, I would store the data for what urls have required referers somewhere in a db table and use a filter to handle all of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the request object to decide.
For ex :

Use `request.getContextPath()` to fetch the "/foo", "/bar" or "/car" and decide whether to allow the access or not.