# Configuring Jetty 10/11 Request Logs

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, jetty-10

I am going through the post [jetty logging](https://docs.huihoo.com/jetty/the-definitive-reference/configuring-jetty-request-logs.html) and trying to figure out what is meaning of every attribute that prints

> 123.4.5.6 - - [27/Aug/2004:10:16:17 +0000]
> "GET /jetty/tut/XmlConfiguration.html HTTP/1.1"
> 200 76793 "http://localhost:8080/jetty/tut/logging.html"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.6) Gecko/20040614 Firefox/0.8"

I am got the answers for some but still not able to figure out for some as mentioned below.

1. 123.4.5.6 : request.getRemoteAddr()
2. dash(-) : not able to figure out
3. dash(-) :  not able to figure out
4. [27/Aug/2004:10:16:17 +0000] : timestamp
5. GET : request.getMethod()
6. jetty/tut/XmlConfiguration.html : request.getRequestURI()
7. HTTP/1.1 : request.getProtocol()
8. 200 : response.getStatus()
9. 76793 : response.getHttpChannel().getBytesWritten()
10. http://localhost:8080/jetty/tut/logging.html : not able to figure out
11. Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.6) Gecko/20040614 Firefox/0.8 : request.getHeader("User-Agent")

Please correct me if I am wrong for other attributes as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent versions of Jetty log requests with the `CustomRequestLog` format.

Which has 2 default "NCSA" formats for output (along with a few others and the ability to customize the format)

1. `NCSA_FORMAT` - syntax declaration of `"%{client}a - %u %t \"%r\" %s %O"`
2. `EXTENDED_NCSA_FORMAT` - syntax of `NCSA_FORMAT` + `" \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""`

So, according to the documentation on `CustomRequestLog`, that means that the following output ...

> 123.4.5.6 - - [27/Aug/2004:10:16:17 +0000] "GET /jetty/tut/XmlConfiguration.html HTTP/1.1" 200 76793 "http://localhost:8080/jetty/tut/logging.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.6) Gecko/20040614 Firefox/0.8"

is actually one of the extended NCSA formats.

Broken down like this ...

1. `123.4.5.6` : the `%{client}a` which is the `request.getRemoteHost()`
2. `-` : the `-` a hardcoded string of `-` in Jetty, that entry would have been the "remote log name user", but since Jetty doesn't support identd, we don't have a means to fill this value out (identd is old school tech that never saw a big adoption for http)
3. `-` : the `%u` which is the authenticated user name, which comes from Jetty internal APIs (eg: `Request.getAuthentication()` or `Authentication.getUserIdentity()` - this only works if your webapp is using Servlet security / authentication / authorization - custom authentication techniques will not have this entry filled out.
4. `[27/Aug/2004:10:16:17 +0000]` : the `%t` which is the Jetty API `Request.getTimeStamp()` which is set in stone when the request was finished being parsed, but before its dispatched to a handler or webapp for processing.
5. `"GET /jetty/tut/XmlConfiguration.html HTTP/1.1"` : the `\"%r\"` which is the raw "Request Line" used in HTTP. Which is the first line of the HTTP request. (or `request.getMethod()` + `request.getOriginalURI()` + `request.getProtocol()`)
6. `200` : the `%s` which is the status as committed on the response obtained from the Jetty internal API `response.getCommittedMetadata().getStatus()` (this API exists because the `HttpServletResponse` is mutable, and many webapps tend to modify it after it's been sent which would mean we log a value that wasn't actually sent if we used the standard servlet API here)
7. `76793` : the `%O` which is the bytes sent on the network as part of the response which comes from the Jetty internal APIs `response.getHttpChannel().getBytesWritten()`
8. `"http://localhost:8080/jetty/tut/logging.html"` : the `\"%{Referer}i\"` which is request `Referer` line (yes, it's spelled incorrectly, but there's ancient HTTP history here for why that's the case).  It comes from `request.getHeader("Referer")`, which can be empty in many cases.
9. `"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.6) Gecko/20040614 Firefox/0.8"` : the `\"%{User-Agent}i\"` is the same as above, but for the `User-Agent` request header.

You can customize this output in countless ways, just read the `CustomRequestLog` apidoc and create a format of your own that has what you want and/or what you are looking for.

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/latest/org.eclipse.jetty.server/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CustomRequestLog.html

Answer (score 2):

Jetty logs in the [NCSA](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Config/Logging.html#common-logfile-format) format by default. According to that,

- (2) would be the RFC 931 "remote log name of the user"
- (3) would be the "The username as which the user has authenticated himself"

Not sure, but I don't think that any of these will have a value anytime.

- (10) this is the referrer (the page which led to this request via a hyperlink), the data is in the header - see [Stack Overflow question 2648984](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648984/httpservletrequest-how-to-obtain-the-referring-url)

Comment: do you also know about (10) ?

Comment: Oh, I missed that one. I edited the response above.