# Time taken by the request in jetty 10 logging

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, jetty-10

This is follow up question for [configure jetty logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112100/configuring-jetty-10-11-request-logs/69115754#69115754). Is there any attribute that gives the time taken by the request?

> 123.4.5.6 - - [27/Aug/2004:10:16:17 +0000] "GET /jetty/tut/XmlConfiguration.html HTTP/1.1" 200 76793 "http://localhost:8080/jetty/tut/logging.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.6) Gecko/20040614 Firefox/0.8"

The above params are already defined in the [configure jetty logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112100/configuring-jetty-10-11-request-logs/69115754#69115754). but I do not see any param that gives us the time taken by the request.

Note - it used to be called log latency in the jetty9 - [jetty9 custom logging](https://portail.capsana.ca/doc/9.4.5.v20170502/configuring-jetty-request-logs.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to change the format string of `CustomRequestLog` to include the `%T` percent code. This is documented in the javadoc for `CustomRequestLog`.  (see https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/latest/org.eclipse.jetty.server/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CustomRequestLog.html)

- **%T** - The time taken to serve the request, in seconds.
- **%{UNIT}T** - The
  time taken to serve the request, in a time unit given by UNIT. Valid
  units are ms for milliseconds, us for microseconds, and s for
  seconds. Using s gives the same result as %T without any format;
  using us gives the same result as %D.

If you are not using `CustomRequestLog` and extending `RequestLog` yourself you can get the latency yourself by doing:

```
long latency = System.currentTimeMillis() - request.getTimeStamp();
```